# ternary expression breaks in babel/webpack vue3

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, vuejs3

I am trying to serve or build my application and it breaks on the following

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (15:41)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
 * ../node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|   computed: {
|     typeComponent: function () {
>       let type = this.line.type ?? 'standard';
```

Any ideas? it says i need a specific loader.

Answer (score 1):

You could either configure your babel to support ES11, otherwise you can also remove the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).